# I need to create a 10x10 multiplication table, and i keep getting errors

Tags: java

I need to create a 10x10 multiplication table. Now I have this but it has errors I would like to fix.

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n=10;
            int i=1;
            int j=1;
            while (i <= n)
            j=1;
            while ( j <=n)
                printf("  %3d", i * j);
                j=j+1;
                System.out.println();
                i=i+1;
            }
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: `printf`? Did you mean `System.out.printf`?  Also, your while loops aren't compounding (one should be wrapped in the other)

Comment: Yes sorry i meant System.out.printf

Comment: Also, use a `for-loop`, it would be simpler

Comment: ok, that s a good idea, i will try to do it using for loop

Comment: the fact that you're not enclosing the body of the loop may also cause unexpected results; `while(condition)` with no braces only executes the next statement, regardless of indentation

Comment: yes, the errors are pretty much that i get no output, but changing the printf that gets solved.

Answer (score 3):

Well, `printf()` alone doesn't exist in java for starters.  Second, you need to use brackets to contain loops.  Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   for (int i =1; i <= 10; i++){
        //cycles through the first number to multiply

        for (int b=1; b <=10; b++){
            //cycles through second number to multiply
            System.out.print(i*b + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This code worked for me, I hope it works for you!

Comment: You're incorrect in regards to [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Really, I have never seen it used in java.

Comment: I know `System.out.printf()` exists.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I don't know about `System.out.printf()`.  I have never used it or seen it used.

Comment: Oh ok, if someone knows, i would like to know. thankssssssss guys

Comment: @mariaandreaerramouspe because you can't just write `printf` unless you've used static import. You should use `System.out.printf()` or `System.out.format()`

Comment: Oh ok just incomplete, i thought they meant at all, because i had seen it before, but yes with System.out...